# advice to run search query in 120 millions data,which way?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, codeigniter

i have mysql database(InnoDB) with +120 millions products data , database is just 5 data table categorys,
products,
category_product_mapping,
users,order

usualy i work for small projects and havent experience in large databases,and i use php+mysql with codeigniter framework and also i use asp.net with mssql,i need small script for this database to search products with name.user login to system and search product with name and see price and add to basket and make order. which way is better ? codeigniter framework with php+mysql or asp.net with mysql?asp.net can be maybe more faster because if iss output cache?

Comment: As long as indices are used (and stats are up-to-date), 120 million rows are a drop in the bucket .. and queries against such are not particularly problematic. Caching is normally used a layer on-top-of queries/SQL, but not replacing the data/query backend.

Comment: no we use both platforms php with mysql and we use asp.net with msssql but for this project i can try to use asp.net with ready mysql database and maybe iss cache can help for speed because we plan to around 50.000 dailly hits and some time possible to have 500 request a second beacuse of large online users in same time in system

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are retrieving large quantities of data (that is, result sets with many rows and / or columns) from this database.  The performance difference between various client technologies -- php / dot net / etc -- is therefore not your biggest problem. Do what's easiest for you to code, test, and maintain.  It's impossible to answer questions about your database performance without a great deal more information.